# How to write text from right-to-left in Central Asian Languages group fonts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

Can anyone help me with this problem:

I am having problem with Right-to-Left writing with the Old Turkic font.

Turkish is written with extended Latin letters left-to-right but:

Old Turkic is a Turkish variation which is written Right-to-Left, defined in

```
Unicode Standard 5.2 Range 10C00-10C4F (Central Asian Languages group).
```

I have all the Unicode fonts with this range that support both the characters codes defined by the standard and the glyphs are ok.
I also use a custom designed keyboard layout designed with Microsoft Keyboard Layout Designer (MKLD).

In the design test window I can write from Right-to-Left as it should be. I can also write Right-to-Left without problems in the default Windows Notepad.

Now what heppens in Adobe Illustrator CS6 and Photoshop CS6:
In Illustrator the only problem is Right-to-Left writing. But the glyphs are ok:

Screen shot of Adobe Illustrator CS6:

[image: First Screenshot]

Now when I copy paste this text to Photoshop I only see empty boxes incase of letters(glyphs):

Screen shot of Adobe Photoshop CS6 Part-1:

[image: Second Screenshot]

When I change `Edit > Preferences > Type > Text Engine` settings of Photoshop From Middle Eastern to East Asian, I can see the glyphs when I rewrite the text (not on the text previously written) but I lose the right-to-left writing feature:

Screen shot of Adobe Photoshop CS6 Part-2:

[image: Third Screenshot]

Some additional files that might be relevant:

> The keyboard layout can be downloaded on my dropbox from here:
>
> [https://www.dropbox.com/s/siddv9k7mjafzpr/Gök%20Türkçe%20Q%20Klavye%20Düzeni.rar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/siddv9k7mjafzpr/G%C3%B6k%20T%C3%BCrk%C3%A7e%20Q%20Klavye%20D%C3%BCzeni.rar)
>
> (foreign characters not recognised by SE, but copy-and-pasting the link works)
>
> The font file `turkic.tff` can be downloaded on my dropbox from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv16xs42nkuk21n/Turkic.ttf). (license not specified)

Can anybody help me to make Adobe Photoshop display the characters as I want them, from right-to-left?

Comment: Adobe software is often rubbish for all right-to-left languages unless you bought the Middle East edition, unfortunately, but **there are ways to work around it** - do any of the answers to [this question about Arabic](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8154/make-arabic-text-show-properly-in-adobe-illustrator/) help? -

Comment: The main problem is when I activate Middle East option the glyphs can not be seen. Becaouse the "Old Turkic" in Unicode standard is defined in the "Central Asian" group. But it is written right-to-left. When I activate "East Asion" options I can see the glyphs but without right-to-left writing. ????

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this in my blog. It's a photoshop script that repairs text layers written in Arabic or Ottoman which writes from right to left. It is for Arabic or Ottoman language, but I hope it will work on Göktürk language.

You can [download it from here](http://www.ferdicildiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/photoshop-arapca-yazi.zip).

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. I think it's not the problem of language but problem is in your Photoshop Software.

On the other hand, I have noticed in your screen shot when you type on Illustrator then you select your Local front but when you type in Photoshop then you are not. It cloud be a problem.

And finally when you Solve your software problem then you can type easily in Photoshop & select the front and chose the alignment as your wish.