# Why does Illustrator add zeeros in all units?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an annoying problem with my Illustrator CC 2015. When specifying some size like font size, two zeros is always added to the size. This causes the font to resize to something huge when the size field is klicked next time. Why does this happen?

Example:

Specifying "12 pt" will make the font 12 pt but the size field instantly change to "12 00 pt" so that it will go crazy next time I want to change the size.

Comment: I can't reproduce this here. It appears to be a tech support issue and therefor off-topic.

Comment: What are your language settings? Maybe you have it set to a language that uses `,` as a decimal point, Adobe forgot about these languages in some update, and now illustrator is storing the number as `12,00` (twelve point zero localised) when saving it, changing that to `12 00` because some adobe engineer told one part of the system to always ignore commas in numbers, and then reads that as `1200`... Adobe are pretty terrible with international stuff ([for example](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8154)), so this seems like the kind of mistake they'd make.